# Vim crashing when pressing `ctrl-s` in terminal

Tags: linux, vim, debian, terminal, crash

When I press `ctrl-s` in vim running in the terminal the program crashes to the point where it doesn't even terminate when I send `kill -SIGKILL <vimPID>`. The process isn't listed in the output of `ps` anymore, but the window with the crashed program remains.

I'm using vim version 7.3, debian wheezy. This happens independent of the window manager even in the plain terminal without the X-server.

What is the reason for this behavior? Any workarounds possible?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See these questions and their accompanying answers on unix.stackexchange:

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> hang terminal emulator?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72086/ctrl-s-hang-terminal-emulator)

[How to unfreeze after accidentally pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal)

In short, Vim's fine<sup>1</sup>, it's your terminal pausing for, as usual, historical reasons. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> to resume.

---

1) Okay, Vim might not be fine after `SIGKILL`ing it, but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> didn't hurt it.